# Account deletion cancelled

Tags: discussion

I have recently tried deleting my superuser account, but it keeps getting cancelled even though I have not.

Currently have 604 points 3 silver and 4 bronze could that affect why it's not qualified for deletion?

This is third time I have tried deleting my account.

Comment: I think 500 rep is kind of the 'magic' number there - and the deletions seem to be done by the system, not manually. If the current attempt fails, might want to use the contact us link to get someone from SE to check - simply cause I'm not quite sure what's happening as a mod.

Comment: Related: [Accounts still there hours after deletion countdown completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248200/191655)

Answer (score 5):

You've cast a fairly significant number (879) of votes. According to [this MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/260822/295684), accounts with lots of votes are held up for manual review by Stack Exchange staff. This is done to [preserve legitimate votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268608/295684) without keeping fraudulent ones. If a manual review is necessary and not carried out before the deletion clock runs out, the account will not be deleted immediately. Eventually a Stack Exchange employee will get around to reviewing your account's voting patterns, at which point a decision about vote preservation will be made and your account will be removed.

Comment: I thought it was actually done if the account has a high rep score? But as JG said, 500+ is probably considered "high" for this check.

Comment: @gparyani there are presently 7,015 500+ users of 611,492 total ([source](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/3/alltime/superuser/)), so only 1.15% of users are 500+.  I'd agree with SE that such a small percentage counts as "high" :) .